# When you invoke `OnCompleted()` on a C# task awaiter, how do you wait on the new job given inside the OnCompleted call?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My `Controller` object makes calls to a MySQL DB over SSH using Renci.SshNet, since i am connecting to several DB, i turned to multithreading, the function `af.FetchAll()` return a `DataSet`, all of which are added to a list `DataList<DataSet>`, i then ask all tasks to complete, then i will give my `DataList` to writer object to save it to CSV file, The problem is: The code inside the `awaiter.OnCompleted(() =>..etc` is still updating the `DataList` while the file writer is trying to access it, despite me asking the task to complete `foreach (Task t in taskList) t.Wait();` , how can i make sure that the awaiter finished executing before i go on and write the 'DataList' to file

```
    public void Query()
    {
        List<QueryValue> QueriesList = quryValLister.GetQueriesList();
        List<ConnectionValues> ConnectionsList = concValLister.GetConnectionList();
        // iterating over servers 
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        foreach (ConnectionValues obj in ConnectionsList)
        {
            Controller af = new Controller(obj, QueriesList);
            Task<DataSet> taskDataResult = Task.Run (() => af.FetchAll());
            taskList.Add(taskDataResult);
            var awaiter = taskDataResult.GetAwaiter();
            awaiter.OnCompleted(() =>
            {
                DataSet temp = awaiter.GetResult();
                if (temp != null)
                {
                    MyDataList.Add(temp);
                }

            });
        }
        foreach (Task t in taskList) t.Wait();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `GetAwaiter` at all? Why not `await`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't consume `GetAwaiter` in regular code.

If you want to write this asynchronously, you can do this:

```
public Task QueryAsync()
{
  List<QueryValue> QueriesList = quryValLister.GetQueriesList();
  List<ConnectionValues> ConnectionsList = concValLister.GetConnectionList();
  // iterating over servers 
  var tasks = ConnectionsList
      .Select(obj => Task.Run(() => new Controller(obj, QueriesList).FetchAll()));
  MyDataList.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(tasks));
}
```

Or, if you want to write it synchronously:

```
public void Query()
{
  List<QueryValue> QueriesList = quryValLister.GetQueriesList();
  List<ConnectionValues> ConnectionsList = concValLister.GetConnectionList();
  // iterating over servers 
  var tasks = ConnectionsList
      .Select(obj => Task.Run(() => new Controller(obj, QueriesList).FetchAll()))
      .ToArray();
  Task.WaitAll(tasks);
  foreach (var task in tasks)
    MyDataList.Add(task.Result);
}
```

Note that the error handling is different in the synchronous version; exceptions are wrapped in `AggregateException`.