# Why does Task.Wait() not behave as expected with Console.WriteLine() - .NET Core?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, concurrency, task-parallel-library, .net-core

I am trying to understand the basics of async programming a bit better, so I have created the following snippet:

```
private void TaskContinuations()
{
    // Task for counting prime numbers
    Task<int> primeNumberTask = Task.Run(() =>
        Enumerable.Range(2, 3000000)
        .Count(n =>
            Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1)
            .All(i => n % i > 0)));

    var awaiter = primeNumberTask.GetAwaiter();

    // primeNumberTask.Wait(); // Option 1: Waiting but not printing (rather unexpected here)

    awaiter.OnCompleted(() => 
    {
        var result = awaiter.GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    });

    //primeNumberTask.Wait(); // Option 2: Waiting but not printing (kind of expected here)

    Console.Read(); // Option 3: Works and prints as expected
}
```

I understand that I have to prevent the main UI task from stopping to prevent the background task from being terminated. So `Console.Read();` blocks the UI thread, and if I do not hit a key before the prime number tasks completes, the output in the console is correctly `216816`. All clear until here.

So I thought that calling `Wait();` would have the same effect (at least if called before the `OnCompleted` callback) as the main UI tasks blocks and waits for the prime number task to complete. That does happen, but in both cases (Option 1 and Option 2) the main thread waits and then terminates without any output.

Why is that? My expectations of the behavior is the following (which might be off a bit, therefore my question)

1. Main UI thread waits/blocks for the task until it completes, subscribes to the completed task, so the callback is executed immediately, the output print is `216816`. But that does not happen!

or

2. Main UI thread waits/blocks and when the tasks finishes it does so immediately before executing `OnCompleted`. So no output is kind of expected here.

So what am I missing here, Can someone shed light on me?

Comment: Do you still have `Console.Read();` when you uncomment `primeNumberTask.Wait();`. If you don't - the program already returned by the moment it had chance to output anything.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33310175/335858)

Comment: No if I keep Console.Read(); it does print '216816' in all cases. The options given are 'exclusive or' ;-)

Comment: @anytoe if you don't have `Console.Read();` in the option 2 the program quits before `.OnCompleted()` is triggered.

Comment: That would match my expectations regarding Option 2, but what about Option 1?

Comment: It's the same. The `OnCompleted` callback is scheduled to run in another thread.

Comment: OK, so you're saying that for Options 1 (and 2) after Wait(); has completed the main UI thread calls 'OnCompleted', passes in the Action and then terminates the thread which received the Action before it can executed it? I kind of expected the Action to run on the main UI thread

Comment: Not sure, but could it be there's an exception that's being bubbled up and causing a crash? Have you tried wrapping everything with a try/catch?

Comment: If there was an exception it would be thrown when Wait() is called

Comment: There is no UI thread in console app, as there is no UI-context there

Comment: ok fine, foreground thread better?

Comment: *so the callback is executed immediately* As [source comments](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,3009) says, it specially cares to not execute callback immediately in case `Task` already completed.

Comment: I agree. If I add 'Thread.Sleep(50)' (depends on your computer) at the end of the method, I do get the output actually. That's NOT a solution, but I it proves 'zerkms' answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [according MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.oncompleted.aspx), you should not use the `OnCompleted` method, as

> This API supports the product infrastructure and **is not intended to be used directly** from your code.

Second thing is that `OnCompleted` method is being called, well, **after** task is completed. So you have a race condition here - task is completed, and `.Net` tries to execute the method after it, but nothing in your code is waiting for `awaiter`, so the program exits before anything gets printed.

The code you **should** use in this case is [`ContinueWith` task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx), with waiting the second task:

```
private void TaskContinuations()
{
    // Task for counting prime numbers
    var primeNumberTask = Task.Run(() =>
        Enumerable.Range(2, 3000000)
        .Count(n =>
            Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1)
            .All(i => n % i > 0)));

    // continuation
    var awaiterTask = primeNumberTask.ContinueWith(t => 
    {
        var result = t.Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    });

    // wait for everything to execute
    awaiterTask.Wait();
}
```

Please note, that [`ContinueWith` has it's own pitfalls](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), and should be used with caution. Another article about the continuation technics can be found [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html).